# Why can't I join a child process created by ProcessPoolExecutor or Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to manually join and close child processes from either multiprocessing.Pool or ProcessPoolExecutor. However whenever I try to join a child process created by either of those Pools the code hangs indefinitely.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED
from multiprocessing import current_process, active_children

class Example:
    def start(self):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            futures = set()
            futures.add(executor.submit(self.worker))
            done, futures = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
            for task in done:
                res = task.result()
                print(f"Child pid is {res}")
                for child in  active_children():
                    if child.pid == res:
                        print("Child found")
                        child.join()
                        child.close()
                print("Child closed")


    def worker(self):
        print("Worker called")
        return current_process().pid

ex = Example()
ex.start()
```

```py
from multiprocessing import current_process, active_children, Pool

class Example:
    def start(self):
        with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
            task = pool.apply_async(self.worker)

            res = task.get()
            print(f"Child pid is {res}")
            for child in active_children():
                if child.pid == res:
                    print("Child found")
                    child.join()
                    child.close()
            print("Child closed")


    def worker(self):
        print("Worker called")
        return current_process().pid

ex = Example()
ex.start()
```

Output:

```
Worker called
Child pid is 284108
Child found
```

Why?

Comment: See my answer below. But I have no idea what you even think you would be accomplishing if you could join individual pool processes while the pool itself is still available for running tasks or what you think you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiprocessing pool is made up of one or more processes that takes a submitted "task" from an input queue and runs the task until it is complete and then goes back to get the next task from the queue. These processes run until you implicitly or explicitly terminate the entire pool via one of the methods describe below. But the important point is that when you submit a task to the pool (e.g. using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` or `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async`) the specified worker function that you pass to these calls is executed in an already running process and that process cannot be joined until it has terminated and will not terminate unless you take a specific action to terminate it.

But there is no reason for explicitly calling `join` on individual processes in a processing pool **and it will cause you to block** because these processes will not terminate until for a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` pool you either first call `shutdown(wait=True)` and all submitted tasks have completed or you call `shutdown(wait=False)` or if you are dealing with a `multiprocess.pool.Pool` pool, you first call either `terminate` or the sequence `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` (which joins *all* the pool processes , which will terminate when all submitted tasks have completed). But at that point there are no longer any running pool processes. For example, if we call `pool.terminate()`:

```py
from multiprocessing import current_process, active_children, Pool

class Example:
    def start(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=1)
        task = pool.apply_async(self.worker)
        res = task.get()
        pool.terminate() # Now there are no more running processes:
        print(f"Child pid is {res}")
        # This will not find any active children:
        for child in active_children():
            if child.pid == res:
                print("Child found")
                child.join()
                child.close()
                print("Child closed")


    def worker(self):
        print("Worker called")
        return current_process().pid

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = Example()
    ex.start()
```

Prints:

```None
Worker called
Child pid is 18076
```

Or if we wait for all tasks to complete and the pool processes terminate of their own accord:

```py
from multiprocessing import current_process, active_children, Pool

class Example:
    def start(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=1)
        task = pool.apply_async(self.worker)
        res = task.get()
        # wait for all tasks to complete:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(f"Child pid is {res}")
        # This will not find any active children:
        for child in active_children():
            if child.pid == res:
                print("Child found")
                child.join()
                child.close()
                print("Child closed")


    def worker(self):
        print("Worker called")
        return current_process().pid

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = Example()
    ex.start()
```

Prints:

```None
Worker called
Child pid is 19936
```